# Service freezing activity before UI has inflated

Tags: android, android-service-binding

I have a long-running service that is bound to a loading screen. I know this is suboptimal, but an AsyncTask did not work for me as it keeps running (data leaks) even after the Activity is ended forcefully. Regardless, want to understand what is happening here. The basic layout never shows up (black screen), but the service runs as intended. A (bound) service lives and runs on the activity thread, of course. But why does it not inflate the UI *first*? onCreate gets called before bindService afaik and as the Log confirmed.

```
 ServiceConnection _connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            _service = myService.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);
            runStuff();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            _service = null;
        }
```

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        serviceIntent.setPackage(myService.class.getPackage().getName());
        serviceIntent.setAction(myService.class.getName() + ".ACTION_BIND");
        bindService(serviceIntent, _connection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loadingscreen);
        findViewsById();
        setDefaultVisibility();
    [...]
```

Edit: As additional info, it actually takes a long time to display the (very simple) loading screen even with the AsyncTask. But even that weird delay should still not matter, because the service should not bind before then. What am I missing?

Edit2: I added timestamps. The service starts immediately. If the service is in an AsyncTask, the UI still takes the same time to load. From the button tap on the previous activity to onPostCreate it takes about 400ms, not the 3-4 s I see looking at the UI. The AsyncTask does update the UI as expected, but apart from onProgressUpdate, there is nothing pertaining to UI after onCreate or before any service calls. What could cause such a delay? I don't even have that on activities in the same app that are heavy on DB and GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a seperate method, I dont know if this will work but i have had success like this

```
private void start(){
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        serviceIntent.setPackage(myService.class.getPackage().getName());
        serviceIntent.setAction(myService.class.getName() + ".ACTION_BIND");
        bindService(serviceIntent, _connection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

and then start that method in your oncreate the service will then start after creation like

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_loadingscreen);
            findViewsById();
            setDefaultVisibility();
start();
        [...]
```

Comment: Does not seem to change anything, unfortunately. I not sure why it *could* help, after all, OnCreate gets called before onStart.

Comment: Oh yes, Sorry what I saw from your code is the onstart gets called before oncreate, anyhow what is the service doing? Syncing data to a server? Sendinf JSON data ?

Comment: The services triggers read and write operations to be written to an external communication bus. Time-consuming stuff, probably comparable to scheduled sending and receiving data. The service itself works perfectly for my purposes, it's just the time discrepancy between the service starting its operations (immediately after button tap of previous activity) and the UI loading. I am fine with the UI being blocked for the duration of the service (as a temporary measure), but I don't understand why it does not at least become visible and then freeze. It takes several seconds.

Comment: I might have a solution, You could add a progress dialog, until the service is finished and THEN you load your UI,  so button tap -> service and progress dialog starts -> service finishes, Progress dialog dismiss -> load UI, You would have the time discrepancy but there would be a visual thing for the user to see and know there is background stuff going on ,Seeing as you are fine with the UI being blocked for the duration